# restore system program settings after a windows crash

Tags: windows-10, backup

Whilst shutting down my PC, my computer was stuck on the shutting down process, it took quite a while displaying the shutting down animation(~20 min). Finally I decided to hold the power button, and as expected next time I booted, it did the disk repair auto process.

Now, all my application settings have been reset to default. It seems I hadn't even created a system restore point, and doing all the settings for my programs is a real pain. Is there some way I could get the settings/customization for my applications back?

Comment: Sounds like you’re currently using a temporary user profile. Can you confirm that’s the case?

Comment: If you have run into the temporary user profile bug, Microsoft’s workaround is to boot into Safe Mode once and everything should return to normal when you then boot normally. ([link](https://www.windowslatest.com/2020/09/15/windows-10-september-2020-update-issues/)) But you should have received the message "You've been signed in with a temporary profile".

Comment: System Restore is of minimal help. For safety, make a complete *disk image* on other media.

Comment: thanks for all the replies, but I didn't actually get a temporary user profile message as mentioned above. I ended up settings my profiles for applications manually. Thankfully this doesn't usually happen